# Replace rather than push on a react router <Link> element (v3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component which will change the query string to facet a search. It looks basically as follows:

```
export default function Facet({ property, value, label }: Props) {
  return (
    <Link
      to={(location) => ({
        ...location,
        query: {
          ...location.query,
          [property]: value,
        }
      })}
      className={styles.facet}
      activeClassName={styles.active}
    >
      {label}
    </Link>
  )
}
```

However, this *pushes* to the browser history, meaning that when they click back, it will go back to the previous facet.

Instead, I am trying to run a replace. [I notice there is an `onClick` handler, which I believe can be used to intercept and replace](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#to), but not sure of the exact method to go about it.

How would you replace rather than push on a react-router Link element?